# java.lang.VerifyError: Invokedynamic bytecode is not supported in this class file version

Tags: java, jvm, verifyerror

I have the following code:

```
private ClientHttpRequestInterceptor accountHeaderInterceptor(){
   return (request, body, executor) -> {
       HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
       headers.add("some header","some value");
       return executor.execute(request,body);
   };
}
```

Compiled with java8. When I am trying to run it on Tomcat 8 with Java 8 I'am getting an

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: Invokedynamic bytecode is not supported in this class file version
```

that points to this method.
What is the reason of this error?

Comment: Invokedynamic came in java 7. Imho you compiled with a target runtime <= java 6
try a `javap -verbose ClientHttpRequestInterceptor | grep "major"` => it must give you something like 51 or 52